# iOS - Remove achievement

Tags: objective-c, ios, game-center, achievements

I've started using Game Center in my App but while I'm testing achievements I noticed that I don't know how to delete/reset them. I also tried to go on the Game Center (on the simulator) swipe on the App and delete it. But when I play my App again, the achievements that I've previously unlocked are still there.

There is a way to reset/delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I found "resetAchievementsWithCompletionHandler" method. Didn't know how I missed that before.